# A Silly rand() Not Found Error

Tags: c++, random

I'm developing a little programme to implement some sorts algorithm in C++. I've decided to define a little object for this task which has some generators and sort functions. But, in randomGenerator() function, it gives an "error C3861: 'rand': identifier not found". Even I include ctime lib, it does not go away and I think there is no reason to get this error...

Here is the code:

SortLib.h

```
#ifndef SORTLIB_H
#define SORTLIB_H

#include<ctime>

class SortLib
{
public:

    void randomGenerator( int* userArray, int upperLimit);
    void orderedGenerator( int* userArray, int upperLimit );
    void reverseOrderedGenerator( int* userArray, int upperLimit );

    void insertionSort( int* userArray, int upperLimit );
    void selectionSortSort( int* userArray, int upperLimit );
    void bubbleSort( int* userArray, int upperLimit );
    void mergeSort( int* userArray, int upperLimit );

};

#endif
```

SortLib.cpp

```
#include "SortLib.h"

void SortLib::randomGenerator( int* userArray, int upperLimit)
{

    for(int i=0; i<upperLimit; i++ )
    {
        userArray[i] = ( rand() % upperLimit );
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea about what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: From a reference: *std::rand
  ...
Defined in header <cstdlib>*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this at the start of your code.

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Rand function is included in the C Standard General Utilities Library.